# Get driver values from a text file

Tags: scripting, drivers

I want to make something like a config file for my scenes. This would be a list of different driven properties that could all be changed from one central location, with the ability to load different versions of the text file. For example, if I had a driver controlling a thickness value on a freestyle line set, or a specific material node, I'd want to be able to control it from the text file.

The point of this would be to set global values, and then have lots of different driven values be affected. For example, if I had lots of Distance from Camera modifiers in Freestyle that were all some base value, then modified by the value from my text file, so that I could alter them all globally.

Is this possible?

Comment: Definitely possible.  I'd go about it this way, use custom scene properties as the base properties (variables)  for your drivers.  Make an operator that sets these properties and leverage off the presets system to save different combinations to file.